# Do I need to gather statistics on an Oracle table that has no index?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have an Oracle 11g DB, and some of the tables are truncated and re-imported from a source system regularly.
I have no index on those tables (for import performance reasons), though they have many million rows.
Do I need to gather the statistics of the tables every time I import them?
When I treat the table I need to analyze and process every row anyway.

Comment: Truncate removes the maintenance cost against frequent DMLs, since it brings down the `HIGH WATERMARK ` to zero. Look at my answer below.

Comment: Please stop voting to move these questions to DBA.  This question clearly meets all 4 criteria listed in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  In a data warehouse, this topic is very much a programmer problem, not a DBA problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizer statistics should be gathered after any significant data change.

That's a good general rule to follow.  There are exceptions but a lack of indexes is not a good enough reason.  It's true that one of the main benefits of accurate statistics is deciding whether to use a full table scan or an index access.  But that's only one of the many ways statistics are used.  For example, if Oracle incorrectly believes a table has no rows it may still use a NESTED LOOP on it, which could be disastrous if the table really has millions of rows.

Settings can be modified to reduce statistics gathering time.  Specifically setting the `DEGREE` may vastly improve performance.  11g has a great default `ESTIMATE_PERCENT`, but sometimes it may be useful to use a very low value.  Statistics can also be imported from previous runs, if the data is very similar.

Another factor to consider is that leaving large tables un-analyzed may affect later statistics gathering jobs.  Most databases have a nightly job to gather stale and missing statistics.  Even a data warehouse will often have such a job, but with the assumption that really large statistics jobs will be run manually.  Leaving large statistics jobs to the default processes may overwhelm that system and cause other stale statistics to wait longer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do a `TRUNCATE` every time, Oracle brings the `HIGH WATERMARK` to zero. So, you don't have to worry about incremental maintenance.

But, regarding the query performance while you hit the table, you MUST follow the `NORMALIZATION` rules. Check the query `EXECUTION PLAN`, if you see `FULL TABLE SCAN` for `LOW CARDINALITY`, then you should consider that column to be indexed.

I would suggest `CTAS` method to you if you need to build the table too frequently. CTAS means `create table as select`. It would be much efficient. Also, in addition, you can use `NO LOGGING` and other features as required, to reduce the `UNDO` and `REDO`.